# how to prevent scrollview hiding other layout

Tags: android, scrollview

clicking on edittext inside scrollview need to open other layout that should overlap scrollview(which occupies whole screen).But scrollview is hiding other layout.can anyone please give me a small hint.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RLayout_main"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/homeButton"
            android:layout_width="40dip"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:background="@drawable/home_icon" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="#005288"
            android:text="@string/MyProfile"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RLayout2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/RLayout1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pickup_textView1"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="@string/Title"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/pickup_textView1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/MrRadio"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/Mr"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" >
            </RadioButton>

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/MrsRadio"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/Mrs"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" >
            </RadioButton>

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/MsRadio"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/Ms"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" >
            </RadioButton>
        </RadioGroup>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/required2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/radioGroup1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/star"
            android:textColor="#ff0000"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RLayout3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/RLayout2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/first_name"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/First_Name"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/firstNameEditText"
            android:layout_width="190dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/first_name"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/required3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/firstNameEditText"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/star"
            android:textColor="#ff0000"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RLayout4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/RLayout3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/last_name"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/Last_Name"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/lastNameEditText"
            android:layout_width="190dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/last_name"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/required4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lastNameEditText"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/star"
            android:textColor="#ff0000"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RLayout5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/RLayout4"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/E_Mail"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/eMailEditText"
            android:layout_width="190dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/email"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="textWebEmailAddress"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/required5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/eMailEditText"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/star"
            android:textColor="#ff0000"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
  </RelativeLayout>

 </ScrollView>

     <include
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    layout="@layout/picker" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please , give your xml code

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/RLayout_main"
android:layout_width="Fill_parent"
android:layout_height="Fill_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/homeButton"
        android:layout_width="40dip"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:background="@drawable/home_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="#005288"
        android:text="@string/MyProfile"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RLayout2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/RLayout1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pickup_textView1"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/Title"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/pickup_textView1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/MrRadio"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Mr"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" >
        </RadioButton>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/MrsRadio"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Mrs"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" >
        </RadioButton>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/MsRadio"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Ms"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" >
        </RadioButton>
    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/required2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/star"
        android:textColor="#ff0000"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RLayout3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/RLayout2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/first_name"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/First_Name"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/firstNameEditText"
        android:layout_width="190dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/first_name"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/required3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/firstNameEditText"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/star"
        android:textColor="#ff0000"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RLayout4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/RLayout3"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/last_name"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/Last_Name"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/lastNameEditText"
        android:layout_width="190dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/last_name"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/required4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lastNameEditText"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/star"
        android:textColor="#ff0000"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RLayout5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/RLayout4"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/E_Mail"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/eMailEditText"
        android:layout_width="190dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/email"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="textWebEmailAddress"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/required5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/eMailEditText"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/star"
        android:textColor="#ff0000"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
 <include
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    layout="@layout/picker"
    android:layout_below="@+id/RLayout5"
 />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I kept gravity as bottom since picker layout coming middle of the screen

Comment: remove that android:layout_gravity="bottom" line from inclide tag

Answer (score 0):

Use this code this will help u it has fixed header and footer in that there is Scroll

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/top_bg"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/back_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/back_btn"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
            android:text="Flights"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/flightDetailsLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mainLinearLayout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/gray_bg123"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/innerflightDetailsLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/from"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:paddingLeft="12dp"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:text="Delhi to Banglore, "
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tripType"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:text="RoundTrip"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/innerTripLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tripDate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="12dp"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:text="19 Jan 2013 " 
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/paxText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="for 1 Adults,0 Childs,O Infants"
                android:textSize="12dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Book"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tripDate"
                android:layout_width="84dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="12dp"
                android:text="Rs 10,2345 /-"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bookBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
                android:src="@drawable/book" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/sortFlightLayouts"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/flightDetailsLayout"
        android:background="@drawable/gray_bg123"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="DEL-BLR"
                android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/flight_icon_result" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/time" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/rupee" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/gray_bg123"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="BLR-DEL"
                android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/flight_icon_result" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/time" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/rupee" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_above="@+id/footerLayout"
         android:layout_below="@+id/sortFlightLayouts"
         android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lvDepartures"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/selection_effect"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
        <ListView
             android:id="@+id/lvArrivals"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
             android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:listSelector="@drawable/selection_effect"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footerLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/top_bg" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/filter" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/sort" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```